# function to truly compare Arrays

Tags: php, compare

I have a function which compares two arrays pushed through my function. The problem is, that I can compare the values of the two different arrays based on a count. My code follows:

```
       function Array_Smoke($Array_1, $Array_2)
            {
                    $Return_Array = array();
                    $Array_Count = count($Array_1);             
                foreach ($Array_1 AS $SmokedKeys => $SmokedValues)
                {
                    if (in_array($SmokedValues, $Array_2))
                    {
                        $Return_Array[] = $SmokedValues;
                    }

            }
                if ($Array_Count == count($Return_Array))
                {
                    return "Arrays Match Up"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Arrays Do Not Match Up";
                }
        }



   $Array_1 = array(
        "Primary Key Number 1" => "Primary Value Number 2", 
        "Sub Key Number 1" => "Sub Value Number 1",
        "Sub key Number 3" => "Sub Value Number 3", 
        "Sub Key Number 2" => "Sub Value Number 2",
   );
   $Array_2 = array(
        "Primary Key Number 1" => "Primary Value Number 2", 
        "Sub Key Number 1" => "Sub Value Number 1",
        "Sub key Number 2" => "Sub Value Number 2", 
        "Sub Key Number 3" => "Sub Value Number 3",
   );
        echo Array_Smoke($Array_1, $Array_2);
```

how would I modify my function to compare based on both the keys and the values of the arrays?

Comment: why not just use ==? `if($Array_1 == $$Array_2){ // }`

Comment: because experimenting with the equal to operator, is that it will only return a sucession if both arrays in the same order as one another

Comment: you can use `array_diff_assoc($Array_1, $Array_2) and array_diff_assoc($Array_2, $Array_1)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `array_diff_assoc()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: This returns the values which are present in both arrays, not fall over when the arrays do not match up fullstop

Comment: Are you just concerned about efficiency? Because your function could just use `array_diff_assoc` internally and then check for an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

OK,you could use builtin php operator like this:

```
function Array_Smoke ($array1, $array2) {
    return $array1 == $array2;
}
```

regarding to [PHP Array operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) '==' operator returns true ifboth arrays have same key/value pairs.

Comment: because experimenting with the equal to operator, is that it will only return a sucession if both arrays in the same order as one another

Comment: No, regarding to above link it checks order if you use `===` operator and `==` just checks for equal key/value pairs.

Comment: I just wrote a simple script to test it and it works as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like array_diff_assoc() is what you need. If nothing is returned then the arrays match. Just remember that the key and the value must match.